# When creating Google Cloud service accounts do you have to authorize the key after you create it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When you make a Google Cloud service account using the gcloud command line interface there's a `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create` to create a key. Looking in the web console, it appears that command creates and registers the key with the account.

Is that sufficient to active the service account for use with they generated JSON key file? Or do you also have to call:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <IAM> --key-file=<JSON file from the keys create command>
```

The Google docs are a little unclear here as to whether that last step is necessary or not. The console shows no changes to the service account but the command executes successfully if you do make the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a key via `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create` does NOT immediately make it available to use with gcloud commands. You indeed need to activate via `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

Use

```
gcloud auth list
```

to view your set of credentials. Moreover gcloud uses currently active credentials. You can view your current settings by running

```
gcloud config list
```

Also it is possible to use various credentials just by adding extra `--account` flag to any `gcloud` command. For example:

```
gcloud compute zones list --account my_account@gmail.com
```

where account is previously was obtained via `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud auth activate-service-account` and appears in `gcloud auth list`.

Comment: > `does NOT immediately make it available to use with gcloud`.

But can I use the SA and key in a GKE container (since that's not "with gcloud") without activating?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use activate-service-account. You can instead use the environment variable 'CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE' to specify your service account json key.

```
CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE="./service-account.json" \
  gcloud deployment-manager deployments \
  create $DEPLOYMENT \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --template resources.jinja \
  --properties deployment:$DEPLOYMENT,project:$PROJECT
```

I found this option here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/848580/how-to-use-google-application-credentials-with-gcloud-on-a-server